# Коллизия объектов Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня есть 2 объекта - Персонаж и монетка.
У монетки есть ключ со значением true, и пока она true я рисую монетку на холсте.
Вот условие с коллизий

```
if(player.x + player.width >= coin.x && player.x + player.width <= coin.x + coin.width) { 
 coin.status = false; 
 player.score++; 
 }
```

Статус монетки становится false и она больше не рисуется при пересечений объектов. Проблема в том, что я не могу сообразить как мне прибавить очко игроку нормально. У меня получается, если находится в этом диапозоне, то очки будут прибавляются бесконечно.
Игра находится в бесконечном цикле, где все перерисовывается. Поэтому я вызываю функцию генераций монетки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю так:

```js
if (player.x + player.width >= coin.x && 
    player.x + player.width <= coin.x + coin.width) { 
   
  if (coin.status) {
    coin.status = false; 
    player.score++; 
  }
  
}
```